# Windows Hello camera gets turned off after some time - how to increase or disable this timeout?

Tags: windows-10, camera, windows-hello

I have added a Hello-capable camera to my Windows 10 (20H2) PC so that I can log on with face recognition without touching the keyboard our mouse. This generally works fine. However, after some time (a few minutes?) the camera disables itself and I need to either type in the PIN or change the sign-in options to face recognition again - all of this defeats the purpose of the camera.

Is there a way I can disable this timeout alltogether or, as a minimum, set it to a really long time (like 48 hours or more)?

Comment: I did try creating a boot PML file and see reference to `C:\Windows\System32\WinBioPlugIns\FaceDriver\HelloFace.inf`. In that I found values such as CaptureIntervalInMilliseconds, PresenceStabilizationThreshold, PresenceLifetimeInSeconds.  A Google for these came up with: https://github.com/TheChaseJ/Win10Services_RegSet_Default/blob/master/Windows_Biometric_Service.reg.  In my PML I did find a `Name Not found` for: `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\WbioSrvc\Service Providers\FacialFeatures\Virtual Sensors\{063436EF-2F27-4B5F-9192-A31BE552253B}\Configurations\0` so that GUID is the same.

Comment: Maybe under: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\ROOT\WINDOWSHELLOFACESOFTWAREDRIVER\0000\Device Parameters\WinBio\Configurations\0` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\ROOT\WINDOWSHELLOFACESOFTWAREDRIVER\0000\Device Parameters\WinBio\Configurations\1`

Comment: Thanks for the detective work :-) My Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WbioSrvc\Service Providers\FacialFeatures is pretty empty, just two empty keys "Global Configurations" and "Virtual Sensors". The HKLM...\controlset001\... looks like the example key on github line 123. Unfortunately, none of these parameters indicate a timeout when face recognition gets disabled. (The timeout is currently less than 1 minute,)